# Count times a function is referenced in code

Tags: c++, function, reference

I want to find a way to keep track of the number of times a function is referenced in the code using a macro (or anything really, just be updated compile-time).

Let's say I have this code:

```
void n(int* d, int x) {
    functionCall();
    *d += x;
    functionCall();
    return;
}

printf("called=%d", TIMES_CALLED);
/* called=2 */
```

Basically something like this. I need to make sure it is accurate too, so anything would help.

Comment: Well how could I use that with VS?

Comment: @FredLarson I do not think profiling tool will help here, OP wants referenced count, not called.

Comment: @FredLarson "So times it was referenced in code, not called." I think this is pretty clear.

Comment: @FredLarson Well I thought that my title was good enough on the issue. So is that do-able? I figured maybe there is a macro that would do the job since there are some that do stuff like that but had no luck actually finding anything for my issue specifically

Comment: @Itsenough1 I doubt macro will help here. One solution would be to parse preprocessor output with regexp, but that maybe inaccurate. Proper way is to use AST from clang

Comment: Maybe comment out the declaration and definition and then count the compiler errors that refer to the missing declaration? [Works with clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89d837ff08506976).

Comment: @wally well that wouldn't be any better than just counting them myself. Ok I guess, will do if there is no easier way

Comment: @Itsenough1, sounds interesting but, IMHO almost senselessly. You can try to implement it at compile time using template wrapper around your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macro [`__COUNTER__`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b0084kay.aspx) expands to an integer literal that starts at 0 and is incremented by 1 every time it is used in a source file or included headers of the source file. `__COUNTER__` remembers its state when you use precompiled headers. This macro is always defined.

```
#include <iostream> 

template<typename T> 
struct Counter 
{

    template<int>
    static void MyFunction()
    {
        std::cout << "Do smth." << std::endl;
    }
};

#define CountMe MyFunction<__COUNTER__>

int main()
{

    Counter<int>::CountMe();
    Counter<double>::CountMe();

    std::cout << __COUNTER__ << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

```
Do smth.
Do smth.
2
```

Comment: This is limited to a single translation unit though